# Searching data in the App itself

Tags: android

I've made an Android music app and everything works fine.Instead of making search on the action bar i decided to make a layout for searching music. I've tried searching online various tutorials but all didn't meet how i would want it to happen,So if anyone would direct me straightly how to implement searching the music within the app itself thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to use search widget, which you can place anywhere in your layout.
Here is a simple tutorial: http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/04/simple-android-searchview-example.html

From Android Documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

> The search widget is an instance of SearchView that you can place anywhere in your layout. By default, the search widget behaves like a standard EditText widget and doesn't do anything, but you can configure it so that the Android system handles all input events, delivers queries to the appropriate activity, and provides search suggestions (just like the search dialog).

Answer (score 0):

First declare your `SearchView` in your Activity, and `implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`, and then process your search process in `onQueryTextChange` method.

```
@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
        //get search query from searchView
        String mquery = query.toLowerCase();

        if(songArr.length() != 0 && songArr != null)
        {
            final JSONArray mArr= new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < songArr.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    String text = songArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("SongName").toLowerCase();
                    if (text.contains(mquery)) {

                        mArr.put(songArr.getJSONObject(i));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            yourAdapter = new YourAdapter(YourActivity.this, mArr, this);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
            mScrollAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // data set changed
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```